# Use spring Mapper to map object of Map - Java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapper

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to use Mapper annotation functionality of spring. I would like to use the mapper to map an object of Map in java as follows:

**HostCounters :**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HostsCounters {
    private Map<String,Map<String,Long>> hostsList;
}
```

**Mapper :**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ResponseMapper {
    GeneralResponse toResponse(SevCount sevCount, HostsCounters hostsList, List<RegDAO> Reg);
}
```

**GeneralRespone:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GeneralResponse {
    private List<RegDAO> Reg;
    private HostsCounters hostsList;
    private SevCount sevCount;
}
```

**Error:**

> Can't map property
>   "java.util.Map>
>   hostsList" to " HostsCounters hostsList". Consider to
>   declare/implement a mapping method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
@Mapping(source = "hostsList", target = "hostsList")
GeneralResponse toResponse(SevCount sevCount, HostsCounters hostsList, List<RegDAO> Reg);
```

**But I would strongly advise you to get rid of identical names with different meanings:**

`HostsCounters hostsList ->  HostsCounters hostsLists`